# Action script 3.0 reusable button function

Tags: actionscript-3, button

I am new to AS3.0 and am trying to create a reusable button class. I am working on a quiz game where I have multiple correct and incorrect buttons and instead of copying the same code over and over again I am trying to create a simple way to reuse the code. I am unaware how to do this. I have created various generic button classes and none have worked. I believe the best way would revolve around creating a generic class with a Boolean 'correct' and each button class extends this parent class and sets the correct Boolean true or false. In the parent class there would be a function saying if correct then go to next frame, if !correct go to lose frame. I have tried this but to no avail; any help?

Comment: Show the code you tried already.  That will be a good starting point for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a design question, then no, a button should not know if it's "the correct one" in a given quiz. All logic should be handled by button's parents, whatever type they are. A simple design would do like this: Create a set of buttons with texts, then you `addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,someFunction)` to each, where `someFunction` is one for the correct button, and another for wrong-answer buttons.